# How to disable Current Date's Week in Calendar Control

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I am trying to disable Current date's week in the calendar control. Can anyone tell me how to do this. For example... Today is August 21, 2012. I want that when calendar is loaded is should display the whole week from August 20 to August 25 as Disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use with ondayrender

```
<asp:Calendar ID="id" runat="server" ondayrender="Disabled_DayRender"></asp:Calendar>

protected void Disabled_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (condition) //specify your condition on yours days
        {
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great answer. Another option would be to use [jQuery DatePicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#events), and subscribe to the `beforeShowDay` event and check if it falls in the current date's week, similar to the OnDayRender event above.

Comment: that is the actual problem buddy... i dont know which condition to put here..!!!... can u tell me the condition to select current week??

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate week number of year and then compare it with current date's week number.

```
    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
   {
       if (GetNumber(e.Day.Date) == GetNumber(DateTime.Now.Date))
       {
           e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
           e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
       }
   }
   public static int GetNumber(DateTime dtDate)
   {
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo ciGetNumber = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
       int returnNumber = ciGetNumber.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dtDate, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
       return returnNumber;
   }
```

This would do the trick. Thanks to Princy.